# Finding the manufacturer of the eMMC Host Controller for HP Stream 11 Pro G3 Notebook PC/82A9

Tags: drivers, gentoo, laptop, hp, mmc

I am trying to install Linux on an [HP Stream 11 Pro G3 Notebook PC/82A9](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-stream-11-pro-g3-notebook-pc/11623748/document/c05283034) and need the name of the manufacturer of the eMMC Host Controller so that I can figure out which drivers to enable in the Linux kernel.  Is there a way to find out?

I tried `lspci` and `lsusb`, and I couldn't find any useful information in their output; likewise for `mmc` from [`mmc-utils`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/mmc-utils).  My laptop has a card reader and the controller is Realtek.  However, no other info is given about the eMMC controller.

Output from `lspci`:

[image]

Output from `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b52d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
$
```

Comment: My laptop is: HP Stream 11 Pro G3 Notebook PC/82A9

Comment: Suggest you contact HP Support https://support.hp.com/us-en/contact-hp/product/hp-stream-11-pro-g3-notebook-pc/11623748 and ask them, as I have not been able to find that information in their publicly available documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`cat /sys/block/mmcblk<0/1>/device/manfid` will give the hex value of Manufacturer ID registered in JEDEC. From JEDEC documentation you can find the manufacturer. Also, you can use `cat /sys/clock/mmcblk<0/1>/device/name` to get the model number of the device. Just google searching the manufacturer ID and model number might give you the manufacturer name.